# Express Middleware running multiple times during MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm running the below route to retrieve a list of projects.

```
app.get('/test', function(request, response){
    Project.find({}, function(err, projects) {
      if (err) throw err;
       response.render(__dirname + '/app/test', projects);
    });
});
```

Everything works fine, but I noticed when I add this middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Things!');
    next();
});
```

I log **"Things!"** 7 times (the amount of results returned by the query).

Is middleware mean't to run for each result. I feel like I'm doing something wrong. I'm still learning Node and Express and trying to not pick up bad habits...

Cheers

Comment: Whatt's the content for your `/app/test`. the middleware maybe access for all http requests.

Comment: That's a html file with a handlebars for each loop that lists each project

Comment: is there http request in your each loop?

Comment: Nope. Just html and handlebars elements. Will post it shortly.

Comment: You're right. It's because of http requests. It's because of the stylesheets and javascript file requests. I wrongly assumed it only executed the handlebars section. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.url);
    next();
});
```

Change your middleware as mentioned above and check the output. It helps for debugging. Add the output to the question.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this. This turned up bunch of http requests.

/stylesheets/main.css   etc

Is this a bad thing? I've tried making them direct references to the files but it still occurs. Surely it's not great if the middleware is executing for each reference...

Comment: Essentially, you are correct. You don't want Node executing your middleware for requests where such logic is not necessary, (i.e. static files). In production, you should run nginx or something similar to take care of serving static files, to free node/express from having to serve these requests. See http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-2-using-nginx-to-avoid-node-js-load/